# tableview loads some old data - BUG IN STOCK iOS MUSIC APP

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Not sure how to word this but i am creating a music app and I have a genres tab button which lists the genres as Cells in a `UICollectionView`.

The user then selects a genre, say "Hip-Hop" and the corresponding artists are shown e.g. "Jay-Z, Kanye West, Kendrick Lamar..." etc. If the user selects 'Jay-Z and Kanye West' the albums for them artists are displayed which have the genre predicate applied.

In this instance it's one album "Watch the Throne" and one song within that album. But now if i go back to my genres collection view and select "Hip Hop/Rap" and select "Jay-Z and Kanye West" (Some songs within this album are showing under this genre and one under the other) and then view the albums (only 1 again - "Watch the throne"), it shows only one track instead of 15.

This works both ways. If I selected the album via the "Hip Hop/Rap" genre first, the album would show 15 tracks for both genres, if I select the "Hip-Hop" genre, the album shows one song for both. Somehow the table stores the data for the first clicked genre. I have a set of images to illustrate what i mean but i have to have 10 rep to post images...

Here is the relevant code:

```
class AlbumsInGenreTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var allAlbums : [MPMediaItemCollection] = []
var selectedGenre : NSString!
var selectedArtist : NSString!
let defaultArtwork = UIImage(named: "No-artwork-albums")
var numberOfSongs : [Int] = []
var albumCount = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    var albumsQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    var artistPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: self.selectedArtist, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist, comparisonType: .EqualTo)
    var genrePredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: self.selectedGenre, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre, comparisonType: .EqualTo)

    albumsQuery.addFilterPredicate(artistPredicate)
    albumsQuery.addFilterPredicate(genrePredicate)

    albumsQuery.groupingType = MPMediaGrouping.Album

    self.allAlbums = []
    self.allAlbums += albumsQuery.collections as [MPMediaItemCollection]

    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 50.0, 40.0))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14.0)

    let albumsArtist = self.selectedArtist as NSString

    let albumArtistName = albumsArtist.substringToIndex(min(25, albumsArtist.length))
    self.albumCount = self.allAlbums.count

    for album in self.allAlbums{
        self.numberOfSongs.append(album.count)
    }
    ... more irrelevant code 
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("albumCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as AlbumsInGenreTableViewCell

    var rowItem = self.allAlbums[indexPath.row].representativeItem
    cell.albumName.text = "\(rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as NSString)"

    var trackCount : AnyObject? = numberOfSongs[indexPath.row]

    if(trackCount != nil){
        cell.albumDetail.text = "\(self.numberOfSongs[indexPath.row]) tracks"
    }
    ... more code
    return cell
}
```

The data at the top of the class is passed from the previous `ViewController` with:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "albumsInGenre"{

        let albumsVC = segue.destinationViewController as AlbumsInGenreTableViewController
        var selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)!.row
        var selectedItem = self.allArtists[selectedIndex].representativeItem
        var artistsName = selectedItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist) as NSString
        albumsVC.selectedGenre = self.selectedGenre as NSString
        albumsVC.selectedArtist = artistsName as NSString

    }
}
```

I have tried to use `self.tableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear()` but that doesn't work either. On other genre selections, the view shows the correct data -

It is only when one album is split amongst more than one genre that the table decides to keep the first one that is selected. I hope I've explained my problem well enough.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Link to the images!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz9j1.jpg

EDIT 2:
I attempted to override the prepareForReuse method:

```
class AlbumsInGenreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var albumArt: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var albumName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var albumDetail: UILabel!

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.albumDetail.text = nil
    self.albumName.text = nil
    self.albumArt.image = nil
}

}
```

Still receive the same result unfortunately

EDIT 3:

After the prepareForReuse() method didn't work, i was led to believe that the views are sending incorrect data amongst one another (Genre). I then set the title as the albums view as the genre it had received from the previous view controller but even this was fine. I then tried implementing viewWillAppear() and redid the mediaQuery in here as well as removing all values from the array when the view first loads. Unfortunately, none of this has worked. I really cannot see where i have gone wrong. I have also tried to reloadData in the viewWillAppear() to no avail. My next attempt will be to return the entire numberOfSongs array from the previous view controller. I have a feeling even if this works, i will then encounter the same problem when i actually go to list the songs within the album.

EDIT 4 - It's an iOS bug:

THIS BUG ALSO EXISTS IN THE STOCK MUSIC APP! I should've checked this a while ago but the exact same thing happens in the stock music app! This is how you can replicate the bug:

1. Have an album split across two genres (Go into iTunes, select X amount of songs from a single album and change the genre to "XXXXXX" and then set the remaining N songs from the album to the genre "NNNNNNN" - Replace 'NNNNNNN' and 'XXXXXX' to genres of your choice.) and then sync your device
2. Go into the stock music app and go to genres, select the 'XXXXXX' genre followed by the album and you will see the X number of songs
3. Now go back and select the 'NNNNNNN' genre followed by the album and you will still see the X number of songs as opposed to the N songs you were expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's an iOS bug - Here is how you can replicate it in the stock music app:

1. Have an album split across two genres (Go into iTunes, select X amount of songs from a single album and change the genre to "XXXXXX" and then set the remaining N songs from the album to the genre "NNNNNNN" - Replace 'NNNNNNN' and 'XXXXXX' to genres of your choice.) and then sync your device.
2. Go into the stock music app and go to genres, select the 'XXXXXX' genre followed by the album and you will see the X number of songs.
3. Now go back and select the 'NNNNNNN' genre followed by the album and you will still see the X number of songs as opposed to the N songs you were expecting.

I've also filed the bug with Apple so hopefully it should be patched in some future update.

Answer (score 1):

Cells are reused. When you get a cell, don't assume it's blank. For example, in this code:

```
if(trackCount != nil){
    cell.albumDetail.text = "\(self.numberOfSongs[indexPath.row]) tracks"
}
```

The text might already be set. You should add an `else` block to set the text to its default state.

You can also reset a cell to its default state in `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: I overrode the prepareForReuse method for the album view controller cells and set the cell labels and images to nil but unfortunately this did not work either. i am getting exactly the same result. I have updated the code above to reflect what i did. Thanks

Comment: Turns out it's a bug that affects every music app including the stock music app. My 4th edit explains what i mean.

Comment: @air6199 Interesting. You should post that as an answer to your question (and file a radar)